# Using Json to format a columns data. Problems with the styling of a columns height

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, json, json-formatting

So I have a column whose data is a multi line field. The problem I am having is it contains a lot of data and stretches out the list. So I tried changing the width and height of the column, but I am having problems. Whenever I change the height, it only shows me the middle of the long list of data. I would like the height to be something like 150px and show the beginning portion of the data and then just fade out the rest of the data that does not fit in the box at the bottom. I already have a working hover feature that shows everything in a pop up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use following Json code.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "display": "inline-block",
    "min-height": "1em",
    "height": "11em",
    "white-space": "normal",
    "padding": "11px 0"
  }
}
```

Result:
[image]